# EEVEE render settings for game assets

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

So I’m using Eevee and I finished creating a game asset. Now I would like to render the final look. However I would like to know what are some things I should change to make my object look decent (some decent lighting, gray background) and any thing else I should consider turning on/off or tuning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eevee is pretty straight  forward, add an HDRI and turn on Ambient Occlusion and Soft Shadows, this should give you a good result already. But this depends on your object, if it's very reflective you might want to calculate reflections.

Comment: Thanks man. I will try it out.